# Player/iFrame switcher - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am building a "player switcher" for my wordpress website. I already have a working code, but it works for iframe only.

Right now I have this HTML:

```
<div class="tab_box" style="display: block;">

<iframe id="show" src="url1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<ul class="play">
 <li class="btn" id="url1">Link 1</li>
 <li class="btn" id="url2">Link 2</li>
 <li class="btn" id="url3">Link 3</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
        x=$(this).attr('id');
            forOk=x.indexOf("videoembed");
            if(forOk==0)
            {x="//ok.ru/"+x;}
        $(".btn").removeClass('main');
        $(this).addClass( "main" )
        $("#show").attr('src',x);       
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly for iframe sources, but I want to use direct .mp4 links in my html5 player (playerjs.com)

The html5 player code is this:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
   var player = new Playerjs({id:"player", file:"video.mp4"});
</script>
```

All I need to do is modify JavaScript so that instead of replacing **"src"** it could replace **"file"** value inside *"new Playerjs"*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [iframe integration](https://playerjs.com/docs/q=iframe) too. Just place your player on the page with 100% covering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
   <head>
      <title></title> 
      <script src='playerjs.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <style>
      html,body{
         margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:100%;
      }
   </style>
        
   <div id="playerjs" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var ps = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("html?")+5).split("&");
      var vs = {id:"playerjs"};  
      for(var i = 0; i<ps.length; i++){
         var p = ps[i].substr(0,ps[i].indexOf("="));
         var v = ps[i].substr(ps[i].indexOf("=")+1);
         if(p!=v){
            vs[p] = decodeURIComponent(v);
         }
      }
      if(vs.file){
         var playerjs = new Playerjs(vs);
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, you place this code in the embed.html file and put it in the player folder. In the same folder should be the player's file (playerjs.js). The iframe code that you embed into the web page will be as follows:

```html
<iframe src="//site.com/player/embed.html?file=VIDEO_URL&poster=POSTER_URL&title=TEXT" type="text/html" width=100% height=100% frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Player variables (file, poster, etc.) can be passed in the iframe query string.